# Error while trying to run react-native on ubuntu

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm trying to run react-native on Ubunty 16.04..When I go to my project folder and type

```
react-native run-android
```

I'm getting the following error

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Please help me solve this issue

Comment: What version of JDK are you using for compilation? Do you have JDK or just JRE?

Comment: I was using version9. I reinstalled android studio using ppa rather than from android studio official website and it's somehow working

Comment: I am having the exact same issue but I have no solution . Any help here ??

Comment: It's been a while, so I don't exactly remember what I did to solve the issue, but from my last comment, I uninstalled and reinstalled android studio using PPA